# Cable Pulldown wrong muscle activation

Tags: exercise, muscle, back

I am doing [this excercise](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/LatissimusDorsi/CBUnderhandPulldown.html)

for back.

But what I felt was that my biceps were getting more tensed than my back, what is I am doing wrong?
P.S. my trainer is worst, dont teach much , but office gym so I have to cope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided shows the exercise being done with the supinated (underhand) grip, and this grip does in fact recruit more of the bicep than doing this same exercise with the pronated (overhand) grip. If your goal is to work your back more with this exercise, I would suggest doing it with an overhand grip so that your biceps don't do most of the work.

Answer (score 1):

The hardest part of working out the back is that your biceps always end up doing work. The best way to minimize this and make sure the back does most of the work is to lower the weight and do it slowly. Make sure you focus your mind on your back when doing the workout.

Another useful tip is to pretend you are doing the pulling from your elbows rather than your biceps, if that makes sense.

Also I would recommend leaning a bit back when doing it and using a wider grip if you wish to workout your back. Watching videos on form can be helpful.